# defining default values

Tags: sas

Im a new SAS User and I have a small problem

I have one large empty table A with lets say 100 columns that I have created with a simple `proc sql; create table`

I have another table B with lets say 40 columns and table C with 55 columns. 
I want to add these two tables into table A, basically I want a table with 100 columns containing the data from table B & C and I'm doing this with a Union command.

Since I dont have values for all 100 variables I have to set default values.
Lets say I have a column named nourishment in table A, food in table B and has no equivalent in table C. I have rules like "If the data comes from table B then value =xxx if its from table C then Value="DefaultValue"

I'd do this easily with R or python but Im struggling with sas.

I'm using SAS sql commands (a Union command)

How do you set default values ? (for all data types : character, numeric or dateI'm using SAS sql commands )

Comment: Unfortunately, SAS Proc SQL does not implement a DEFAULT constraint like other databases.  40 + 55 is not 100, so are there 5 columns in table A ?  You say UNION -- which is for 'stacking' data. However, your "Lets say... example could be describing a merge of data that has a common key between A, B and C."  In SQL that would be a B FULL JOIN C.  UNION ~ Data Step SET and JOIN ~ Data Step MERGE.  In SQL there would be 100 expressions to select each column, and in DATA Step arrays could be used. Please further clarify with a reduced example of A, B and C tables.

Comment: There are 100 columns in A (it says so in the Original post).   I am trying to add in table A the data from B & C. The amount of columns in A +B doesn't have to amount to 100. I just need to add the common variables.

Comment: Why not just attach formats to your variables to label missing values with your defaults?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dates in SAS are actually just numeric values.  Often they have a date format applied to make them readable.

So you could just assign a missing value by default like so:

```
. as ColumnName
```

or any default date like so

```
'17NOV2017'd as ColumnName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
. as MyColumnName
```

SAS can deal with missing values.

Using a specially coded value, such as 'NA', to represent a missing value condition can work but may lead to headaches and extra coding.  Recommended read in SAS help: "Working with Missing Values"

The default SAS missing value for numerics (which also includes dates) is period.

```
. as MyColumnName
```

SAS also has 27 special missing values for numerics that are expressed as . < character >

```
.A as MyColumnName
...
.Z as MyColumnName
._ as MyColumnName
```

The missing value for character variables is a single space

```
' '
'' empty quote string also works
'    ' as does a longer empty string
```

Rule of thumb: be consistent when coding your missing values.

You can use OPTIONS MISSING to specify what character is shown when a missing value is printed.

```
OPTIONS MISSING = '*'; * My special representation of missing for this report;
Proc PRINT data=myData;
run;
OPTIONS MISSING = '.'; * Restore to the default;
```

SAS custom formats can also be used to customize what is printed for missing values.

```
Proc FORMAT;
  value MissingN 
    . = 'N/A'
    .N = 'Special N/A different than regular N/A'  /* for .N */
  ;
  value $MissingC
    ' ' = 'N/A'
  ;
  value SillyChristmasStocking
    .C = 'Bad'
    .O = 'children'
    .A = 'get'
    .L = 'No toys'
  ;
```

The token after the `value` keyword can be any new valid SAS name that you want to used for your format name.

```
Proc PRINT data=myData;
  format myColumnName MissingN.;
  format name $MissingC.;
  format behaviour SillyChristmasStocking.;
run;
```

As for your character missing value conditions, I would continue to use `" "` or `' '`

You mention UNION which is a SQL feature.  In SQL, JOIN also occur, perhaps more often then UNION.  When JOINing and values from two source columns collide, you will want to use either COALESCE() function or CASE 
statements to select the non-missing value.

Comment: I think this answer dives a little too deep into missing values.  They just want to initialize a date value, possibly to missing, or possibly to a default date value.

Comment: I agree, that's why I try to put the short answer at top.  If OP self profess being new that's fine, I'll add some context or information that new people can benefit from.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I didnt word my post properly so I edited it

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using `UNION` in `PROC SQL` at any point in your SAS usage.  `UNION` is almost always inferior to a simple data step, or a data step view.

That's because the data step seamlessly handles issues like differing variables on different tables.  SAS is quite comfortable with vertically combining datasets; SQL is always a bit trickier when they're not identical.

```
data c;
  set a b;
run;
```

That runs whether or not `a` and `b` are identical, so long as `a` and `b` don't have *conflicting* variable names (that aren't intended to be in the same column); and if they do, just use the `rename` dataset option to resolve it.

If you do as the above, and don't use `union`, you'll get a missing value automatically for those dates.

Answer (score 0):

NFN:

## DATA Step

A DATA Step approach for stacking data is the simplest. Use SET to stack the data and array processing to apply your defaults.  For example:

```
data stacked_data;
  set
    TARGET_TEMPLATE (obs = 0)
    ONE
    TWO
  ;

  array allchar _character_;
  array allnum  _numeric_;
  array dates d1-d5;

  do over allchar; if missing(allchar) then allchar = '*UNKNOWN*'; end;
  do over allnum; if missing(allnum) then allnum = -995; end;
  do over dates; if missing(dates) then dates='01NOV1971'd; end;
run;
```

A subtle issue is that any missing values in ONE or TWO will be replaced with the default value.

## Proc SQL

In Proc SQL you will want to create a single row table containing the default values for A.  That table can be joined to the union of B and C.  The join select will involve coalesce() in order to choose the predefined default value when a column is not from B or C.

For example, suppose you have an empty (zero rows), richly columned, target table (your A) acting as a template:

```
data TARGET_TEMPLATE;
  length _n_ 8;
  length a1-a5 $25 d1-d5 4 x1-x20 y1-y20 z1-z20 p1-p20 q1-q20 r1-r20 8;
  call missing (of _all_);
  format d1-d5 yymmdd10.;
  stop;
run;
```

Because Proc SQL does not provide syntax for a default constraint you need to create a table of your own defaults.  This is probably easiest with DATA Step:

```
data TARGET_DEFAULTS;
  if 0 then set TARGET_TEMPLATE (obs=0); * prep pdv to match TARGET;
  array allchar _character_ (1000 * '*UNKNOWN*');
  array allnum  _numeric_   (1000 * -995);
  array d d1-d5 (5 * '01NOV1971'd); * override the allnum array initialization;
  output;
  stop;
run;
```

Here is some generated demo data, ONE and TWO, that correspond to your B and C:

```
data ONE;
  if 0 then set TARGET_TEMPLATE (obs=0); * prep pdv of demo data to match TARGET;
  do _n_ = 1 to 100;
    array a a1 a3 a5;
    array num x: y: z:;
    array d d1 d2;
    do over a; a = catx (' ', 'ONE', _n_, _i_); end;
    do over num; num = 1000 + _n_ + _i_; end;
    retain foodate '01jan1975'd;
    do over d; d=foodate; foodate+1; end;
    output;
  end;
  keep a1 a3 a5 x: y: z: d1 d2; * keep the disparate columns that were populated;
run;

data TWO;
  if 0 then set TARGET_TEMPLATE (obs=0); * prep pdv of demo data to match TARGET;
  do _n_ = 1 to 200;
    array a a1 a2 a3;
    array num x5 y5 z5 p: q: r:;
    array d d1 d2;
    do over a; a = catx (' ', 'TWO', _n_, _i_); end;
    do over num; num = 20000 + _n_*10 + _i_; end;
    retain foodate '01jan1985'd;
    do over d; d=foodate; foodate+1; end;
    output;
  end;
  keep a1 a2 a3 x5 y5 z5 p: q: r:; * keep the disparate columns that were populated;
run;
```

A stacking of A, B and C is simple SQL but does not introduce target specific default values:

```
proc sql noprint;

  * generic UNION stack with SAS missing values (space and dot) for cells
  * where ONE and TWO did not contribute any data;

  create table stacked_data as
    select * from  have_data_TEMPLATE   %*** empty template first ensures template column order and formats are honored in output data;
    outer union corresponding           %*** align by column name, do not remove duplicates;
    select * from ONE
    outer union corresponding 
    select * from TWO
  ;
```

When the stacking is put in a sub-query, it can be joined with the defaults.  The choosing of the target default value for each column involves examining DICTIONARY.COLUMNS and generating the SQL source for selecting the coalescence of stack and default.

```
proc sql noprint;
  * codegen select items ;
  select cat('coalesce(STACK.',trim(name),',DEFAULT.',trim(name),') as ',trim(name))
  into :coalesces separated by ','
  from DICTIONARY.COLUMNS
  where libname = 'WORK' and memname = 'HAVE_DATA_TEMPLATE' %* dictionary lib and mem name values are always uppercase;
  order by npos
  ; 

  create table stacked_data_with_defaults as
    select * from TARGET_TEMPLATE             %*** output honors template;
    outer union corresponding
    select 
      source
    , &coalesces                              %*** apply codegen;
    from 
    (
      select * from  WORK.have_data_TEMPLATE  %*** ensure fully columned sub-select that will align with coalesces;
      outer union corresponding
      select 'one' as source, * from ONE
      outer union corresponding 
      select 'two' as source, * from TWO
    ) as STACK
    join
      TARGET_DEFAULTS as DEFAULT
    on 1=1 
  ;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you create an empty dataset? What is it going to be used for? Perhaps you want to use it as a default structure definition?  If so and you want to stack B and C and get them in the structure defined by A you could code this way.

```
data want ;
  set a(obs=0) b c ;
run;
```

Not sure what the purpose would be to have default values. Couldn't you use formats if you want missing values to display in special ways?

Or you could create code to default values and perhaps just %include it or wrap the logic into a macro.  So it you had a code file name 'defaults.sas' with lines like this.

```
  startdate=coalesce(startdate,'01JAN2013'd);
  gender=coalescec(gender,'UNKNOWN');
```

Then your little program to make a new dataset that looks like A and uses the data from B and C would look like this.

```
data want ;
  set a(obs=0) b c ;
%include 'defaults.sas';
run;
```

If you really did want to aggregate the records into some large dataset then perhaps you want to use `PROC APPEND` to add the records once they are created in the right structure.

```
proc append data=want base=a ;
run;
```